# Create case sensitive vlookup with array based search key

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following case sensitive vlookup formula however search_key must be a single value here, and I need to search an array of keys.

`=ArrayFormula(INDEX(return_array, MATCH (TRUE, EXACT(search_array, search_key), 0)))`

Answer (score -1):

try something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(EXACT(A1:A); EXACT(Sheet1!A1:B); 2; 0)))
```